# Differential amplifier input resistance

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, differential-amplifier

From this [link](https://wiki.brown.edu/confluence/download/attachments/1163278/Differential%20Amplifier.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1438365664000&api=v2) the balanced gain and input impedance differential amplifier has such resistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQAIOQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$ R_1 = \dfrac{R_i}{R_i+R_f}R_i$$
$$ R_2 = \dfrac{R_i}{R_i+R_f}R_f$$

From above equations we could observe that input impedance seen from \$V_1\$ shall be \$R_i\$ and impedance seen from \$V_2\$ is \$(R_1+R_2)\$.

Q1: What is the benefit of using such resistances instead of adding a parallel resistance to \$V_2\$?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEPu5g.png)</sup>

Q2: Why in the 3 op amp instrumentation amplifier this kind of balancing is not performed?

[image]

Comment: If both input resistors are \$R_I\$ then the impedance is balanced for common mode input voltages so why go to the trouble of modifying \$R_I\$ in one path and not the other OR adding the extra resistor?

Comment: @Andyaka Because, the differential input stage could be consisted by two transistors and a current source, therefore is desired to have an equal load to both input transistors.